# function doesn't work second time I hover on the div

Tags: jquery, html

I am having a little problem, the text is visible and it scrolls perfectly on mouseenter, and hides on mouseleave but when I mouseover again the function doesn't work.
here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var $container = $("#scrollContainer1"),
        $ps = $container.find("p"),
        containerHeight = $container.height(),
        contentHeight = 0,
        scrollTop = 0;

    ($container).hover(function(){
        $ps.each(function() {
            contentHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
        })

        $("<div></div>").css("height", 150).appendTo($container).clone().prependTo($container);

        setInterval(function() {
            if (scrollTop > contentHeight + containerHeight)
                scrollTop = 0;
            $container.scrollTop(scrollTop++);
        }, 20);

    });
    ($container).on("mouseleave", function(){
        scrollTop=0;
        contentHeight=0; 
    });
});
```

Comment: @usoban -- Thx for edit..was having a nightmare doing it :D

Comment: I dont see `mouseenter` or `mouseleave` here

Comment: @passionateCoder - `.hover()` is a shortcut for those events.

Comment: yeah i knew that.. i guess its night time grogginess :)

Answer (score 0):

@user2431639: Can u put your HTML code too!
Mostly you have to change mouseenter to "onmouseover".

In HTML:

`<element onmouseover="SomeJavaScriptCode">`

In JavaScript:

```
object.onmouseover=function(){SomeJavaScriptCode};
```

Comment: stop this. please :( you could use `on` with jquery events cant you? why this?

Comment: Sorry Bro! I'm newbie. I just shared what I know.

Comment: Edit it use jquery's on() :-)

Answer (score 0):

All I can think of, is the fact that you are inserting new divs into your container. Hover only executes on the top-most layer and looks like the event doesn't propagate down.

My suggestion would be to use `.on()` function to bind your mouse events instead of just hover.

```
$container.on("mouseenter", function(event){
  // mouse in
});
$container.on("mouseleave", function(event){
  // mouse out
});
```

[source](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

The only problem now, is that those events will fire on child elements within your container. So you can't use `this` to refer to $container.

Comment: can you please tell me how this on() function can be used, i am new to jquery.

Comment: Hey @no0bCoder! Any luck with it?